# Horizontal scrolling with dynamically changed the child view size in android

Tags: android

I have a horizontal scrollbar in android in which multiple views (shape is ring) of different sizes are added. The centered view has the largest size and others have less.

I want that when I scroll right to left then the next view of the centered view will be moved to the center and size will be changed and same action on left to right scrolling also.

Please check the attached image. Please help me.

[image]

Comment: is it a period cycle?

Comment: Yes it's a periodical cycle.

Comment: Hi @VivekMittal. Did you find how to create this horizontal scroll?